# Visual Studio Program Using Excel on a PC that doesn't have Excel

Tags: sql, excel, visual-studio

I'm making a program that will eventually be used as a simple program to keep track of customers at a campground. I had originally made an excel spreadsheet for the owner where they could add how much each renter paid per month and I set it up in a way that it totaled each month and the whole year for him and displayed it like an accounting spreadsheet, with double underlines and the like. Now, he no longer has a copy of excel. I have set him up temporarily on google docs, but besides it not having all the functionality of excel, he doesn't trust it on the internet and has a hard time navigating to it.

What I'd like to do is create a program that would use forms to let him easily enter information, but display it either in the excel spreadsheet like he's used to seeing, or something that looks and prints pretty much the same.

I've seen people use SQL to work with access and excel. I'd like the connection string for that if anyone knows it. I have Visual Studio 2013 and I have Excel 2010 at home and work and 2013 at work.

My big question for you guys, that I can't find any information on is whether or not excel will work if I install the program on his computer that doesn't have excel installed? Does it work because it's part of the program? Can I only use the sheets and formulas that I set up when I created it? Can I generate new sheets using the program once it's installed on a pc that doesn't have excel installed on it? Thanks a lot for the help guys. I can't find information on this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what library you use. If you use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` than you will need to have the specific version of excel installed or at least a version that supports your interop assembly (my past experience was that it had to be exact).

The other option is to use another standalone third party library that reads the zipped XML files (.xlsx) and can manipulate it through that. Some libraries worth mention:

- [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/)
- [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)
- [ExcelLibrary](https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/)

Comment: The second option sounds closer to what I'd need. They charge too much for Excel for him to purchase a copy, so I don't think the first option would work. Will the other libraries you mentioned allow you create a new page or just manipulate what you already have? @Michal Ciechan

Comment: They all support Read + Write.